# Get var type value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, var, idataobject

```
var temp = toCheck.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
```

I have the code above in my program. toCheck is an IDataObjecct containing a file(image to be specific) path.

When I debug, I see the value stored under as such:
temp -> {string[1]}
 
[0] -> "C:\....rest of path"

Everything is correct but when I try to access the string inside, I cannot. If I use the toString() method it returns System.String[] but not the filepath.
Any suggestions on how I can retrieve the filepath inside of the variable?

Answer (score 2):

`temp -> {string[1]}` Means that temp is an array of type `string` with one element.

`[0] -> "C:\....rest of path"` Means that the element at index 0 is equal to the path.

Since `GetData` returns the string array boxed as an `object`, you'll also have to unbox it first.  Then you can simply access that element like this:

```
string[] strArr = temp as string[];
string s = temp[0];
```

Comment: Thank you Gunther, I should have mentioned that I tried this.
When I set 
string s = temp[0];

I get the following error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
This is where my confusion comes from. I thought it would be temp[] to access the string but it appears it's not that easy.

Comment: @user4238148 Woops!  Forgot about the unboxing of the `object`.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is an array of strings, that is why you are getting that. If you want to get the first string of the array then:

```
var mystring = temp[0];
```

That should do

Also you can check if the string[] has any string with:

```
if(temp.Length > 0) myString = temp[0];
```

where `myString` is a variable of type `string`

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you provided details on why that solves his problem

Comment: You should explain why that should do it

Comment: I think now it's better

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

```
string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)temp).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Using the above statement you can go from type object to an array of string.
You need to have included `using.System.Linq` for it to work.

```
 var temp = toCheck.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)temp).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
        string path = "";

        foreach(string a in arr)
            path = a;
```

This ended up being all the code if anybody is curious. I iterate over the array because otherwise it would skip the rest of the function when I debugged. Not sure what was causing this but this works. Thank you all for your help!